# nginx "server" directive with multiple "server_name" entries: always first one is passed to PHP's $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']

Tags: php, nginx, configuration, fastcgi

My configuration file has a `server` directive block that begins with...

```
server {
    server_name www.example1.com www.example2.com www.example3.com;
```

...in order to allow the site to be accessed with different domain names.

However PHP's `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` always returns the first entry of `server_name`, in this case `http://www.example1.com`

So I have no way from the PHP code to know which domain the user used to access the site.

**Is there any way to tell nginx/fastcgi to pass the real domain name used to access the site?**

---

The only solution I've found so far is to repeat the entire `server` block for each domain with a distinct `server_name` entry but obviously I'm looking for a better one.

Comment: perhaps use Host in your code instead -http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24host

Comment: Why not creating 3 site configuration files in nginx under \etc\nginx\sites-available to each site pointing to the same location?

Comment: @maytham of course I can do that but it is exactly what I'm trying to avoid (replicating identical configuration files)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Set `SERVER_NAME` to use `$host` in your `fastcgi_params` configuration.

```
fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME         $host;
```

Source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_param

Comment: Up voted you, but why isn't this default behavior, seems logical to me. Why does it use the first item in the server_name block instead.

Comment: Always declare `fastcgi_param` statements after the `include fastcgi_params;` statement to avoid any ambiguity in your configuration files.

Answer (score 11):

This is intended and the proper solution is to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` in your code instead.

You should interpret `SERVER_NAME` as a *verified* server-name, and `HTTP_HOST` as user-input which can be modified quite easily, and thus shouldn't be trusted.

Comment: thank you. This is the simplest solution and I'm probably will go with it. However I would have preferred to find a way to use `'SERVER_NAME'` since it is the name of the virtual host as it's get defined as **nginx** handle the request applying the configuration directives. `'HTTP_HOST'` comes straight from the request header (if the client sent it). Of course a properly configured **nginx** would reject requests with bad http host headers making `'HTTP_HOST'` reliable...

Comment: I understand you're attempting some sort of partial validation in your nginx config; but like you mentioned, a properly configured nginx will only allow *valid* HTTP_HOST entries. Treating HTTP_* as untrusted like other user-input is still a good idea. The distinction between `SERVER_NAME` and `HTTP_HOST` is pretty useful if you understand the difference