# "Flushing" internal Nginx DNS for server_name

Tags: nginx, dns

During testing I had nginx.conf setup as:

```
server {
    listen 107.170.3.157:80;
    server_name  testing.com example.com;
    root /home/example;
    include common.conf;
}
```

Now that things are done and we want to go live, I've removed `testing.com` from that server_name directive above. However we now recognise that in a setup like this, the first server_name is what Nginx seems to like. It keeps redirecting example.com to testing.com!

Reading some help I came up with this `$host` directive:

```
#fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# Based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31479341/nginx-server-directive-with-multiple-server-name-entries-always-first-one-i
fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME       $host;
```

Even with this, and having restarted the Nginx server several times, the domain we want (example.com) is being routed to testing.com. Is there anything else we can do?

Comment: Is this a browser cache issue? Also, use `nginx -T` to both test the configuration and see if there are any references to `testing.com` still in the configuration.

Comment: @RichardSmith can't be a browser issue only as browserstack shows the same behaviour. Those are browsers in completely different places. My entire nginx conf has no other mention of testing.com now. So the caching is elsewhere. I've rebooted nginx and cleared the cache manually that sits in `/var/run/nginx-cache`. Any other ideas?

Comment: Could it be the application behind `nginx`?

Comment: @RichardSmith, it's just Wordpress. Thank you for the nudge. Indeed, in Wordpress "settings" we still had the site_url etc as testing.com. Fixed it, and now it works. Not a clever moment. Thank you!